# Training halt at the first epoch using tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, parallel-processing, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am using Tensorflow data API (Tensorflow 2.0) to train a deep learning model on 4 GPUs. I have 3 CPUs and my CPU utilization is 30%, I have 4 GPUs and my GPU utilization is 100% but I am stuck in first epoch. Here is my code:

```
def get_dataset():
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.05,shuffle=True,random_state=42)
    Train=tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train))
    Train = Train.batch(128,drop_remainder=True)
    Train = Train.prefetch(buffer_size=10)
    Test=tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test,y_test))
    Test = Test.batch(len(x_test),drop_remainder=True)
    Test = Test.prefetch(buffer_size=10)
return(Train,Test,)



train_dataset, test_dataset = get_dataset()
model.fit(train_dataset,validation_data=test_dataset, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=2,epochs=10)
```

Anyone knows what is going on? When I use one CPU and 2 GPUs, then everything works fine! But, When I use 3CPUs and 4GPUs, then I am stuck in first epoch! (Dataset size=400k samples)

Comment: Your train size 99.5% of your data. If your data is 1M samples, you are training with 995.000 samples. If I assume you are training with images with size 28 x 28, then 995.000 x 28 x 28 samples are calculating. My suggestion? Just lower your train data and your epoch size to see how well your model is performing? Assume you wait till the end and you will have a lower accuracy? You may be waiting for lower accuracy?

Comment: The problem is not with test size. Do you know why I am stuck in epoch=1 when I use 3 CPUs and 4GPUs but I am fine when I use 1CPU and 2GPUs?

Comment: Add `repeat()` transformation to your training dataset. Probably your data is getting exhausted after the first epoch. Are you running into any errors? If so, please add them here

Comment: I do not get any error at all. I simply do not get any result for epoch=1 even and I am stuck in epoch=1.  So, where should I add repeat(n)? what shall be n?

Comment: Set `drop_remainder` to False & call `Train=Train.repeat()` before creating `batch()`